# WPF Cefsharp Allow browser notifications programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I am working on a WPF application with CefSharp chromium browser. I have a TabControl where each tab item contains chromium browser and hosts different websites.

Problem:
I am seeing blank screen for one website in one of tab items whereas same website loads fine in standalone browser(Google chrome/Microsoft Edge).

Observations/Analysis:
When website loads in standalone browser(Google chrome/Microsoft Edge), I get a browser popup asking to allow or block notifications BUT I didn't get this popup in my application.
When I opened dev tools for specific chromium browser in my application then I found below error in console:
**ERROR ReferenceError: Notification is not defined**

I know that we can allow or block microphone/camera from C# code like below:

```
CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "1");
Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

Is there any command argument to allow/block notifications like above code ?
Please help.

Comment: As per https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=16009 CEF doesn't support the notification API. You can create a JavaScript polyfill to add basic support.  See https://github.com/Haltroy/Korot/issues/22 for a discussion on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

CEFSharp doesn't support the notification API. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2890 But you can make your own implementation.
Use JavaScript to override the Notification constructor and send a message from CEFSharp to your code by pre-packaging it in JSON.

```
public void OnFrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
{
Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(@"(function(){ class Notification {
    static permission = 'granted';
    static maxActions = 2;
    static name = 'Notification';
    constructor(title, options) {
        let packageSet = new Set();
        packageSet.add(title).add(options);
        let json_package = JSON.stringify([...packageSet]);
        CefSharp.PostMessage(json_package);
        //alert(title);
    }
    static requestPermission() {
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            res('granted');
        })
    }   
};
window.Notification = Notification;
})();");
}
```

Receive a message and put it in the queue. I used [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for unpacking from JSON.

```
private void OnBrowserJavascriptMessageReceived(object sender, JavascriptMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    object[] objArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[]>(e.Message.ToString());
    Options options = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Options>(objArray[1].ToString(), new ImageConverter());
    // Add to Notification queue
    MessageQueue.Enqueue(new object[] { objArray[0], options });
}
```

The MessageQueue is the simple queue of array objects that we then process in another thread.

```
public Queue<object[]> MessageQueue = new Queue<object[]>();
```

The Notifications structure.

```
public class Options
{
    public byte[] icon { get; set; }               
    public string body { get; set; }               
    public string tag { get; set; }                
    public bool canReply { get; set; }             
    public bool silent { get; set; }               
    public bool requireInteraction { get; set; }
}
```

Image converter

```
public class ImageConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(byte[]);
    }
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var str = reader.Value.ToString();
        var index = reader.Value.ToString().IndexOf("base64,");
        if (index == -1)
        {
            try
            {
                // Download the icon
                Task<byte[]> task = App.ImageDownloaderObj.GetImageBytesAsync(new Uri(str));
                task.Wait(500);
                return task.Result;
            }
            catch { return new byte[] { }; }
        }
        else
        {
            var m = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(str.Substring(index + 7)));
            return m.ToArray();
        }
        //return (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(m);
    }
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)value;
        MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
        bmp.Save(m, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        writer.WriteValue(Convert.ToBase64String(m.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Comment: A few comments,  JavascriptMessageReceived is called on the thread pool, so calling MessageBox.Show isn't recommend as there is no message loop running, best to use the UI thread for everything UI related. Be great if the example actually sent the notification text rather than a fixed string.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I made changes. Now it's code actually running in one of the projects.